# Amazon EC2 openVPN instance connection issues

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn

Currently trying to connect to an openVPN server set up on an EC2 instance that is also running a web application.  My client establishes a connection with the server and I can ping the gateway (10.8.0.1) from the client but my routing isn't working.  Here's the output from the OVPN server log immediately after connection:

```
MULTI: bad source address from client [client IP], packet dropped
```

I have ip forwarding set in sysctl, and I have the following iptables rules:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [135:8311]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [135:8311]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s [client IP]/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr 25 17:01:46 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Apr 25 17:01:46 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [16905:2067971]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [16818:2063714]
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

My server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.22
```

My EC2 instance is on the 172.31.0.0 subnet, and has a public ip of 54.88.7.x.

Really not sure where to go from here, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you use the client config directory? /etc/openvpn/ccd/ - create a file in here for you client and add the route "iroute 172.31.0.0 255.255.255.0

Comment: ..also add the path to the client config directory in your server config "client-config-dir ccd"

Comment: I haven't done that, no -- but wouldn't the push "route 172.31.0.0 255.255.255.0" line in my server config do the same thing??